# Create boundary around the object

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have the [input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7uQz.jpg). I want to create the boundary around the object and marked the boundary pixels as gray i.e. 128 intensity value. I need [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdyQv.jpg) type of output image. I traced the boundary of the object:

```
level = graythresh(im);
BW = im2bw(im,level);
figure; imshow(BW);
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
imshow(im);
hold on
for k = 1:length(B)
   boundary = B{k};
   plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'Color', [0.5 0.5 0.5], 'LineWidth', 5)
end
```

But it will only plot the boundary over the image. I want to create this boundary around the object of input image. How can I do this? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Please post the original image (this one has white borders). You want then the boundary on the image? you want to substitute pixel values (thus lose information) to add a boundary layer around it?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know why you wan this, a word of advice: you may not want to do it. You are losing information of the image by doing so. It is possible that for you application knowing the indices of the boundaries is enough, and you do already know them.

However, this is what you would need to do in case of really wanting to do it:

```
clear;
clc;

im=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7uQz.jpg');
im=im(31:677,90:1118);
level = graythresh(im);
BW = im2bw(im,level);
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');

for k = 1:length(B)
   boundary = B{k};

   %%%%%%%%% Fill the boundary locations with he desired value.
   for ii=1:size(boundary,1)
   im(boundary(ii,1), boundary(ii,2))=128;
   end
end
```

If you want "fat" lines as in your image, add this after:

```
im128=im==128;
bigboundary=imdilate(im128,ones(5));
im(bigboundary)=128;
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can binarize the image and detect the contours using OpenCV.
Here is the Python implementation:

```
img = cv2.imread(r'D:\Image\temp1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,bw = cv2.threshold(gray,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bw, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, 1)
for cnt in contours:
    c = np.random.randint(0,256,3)
    c = (int(c[0]), int(c[1]), int(c[2]))
    cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,c,2)
```

Output image:

[image]

Comment: You can replace the color value in cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,c,2) with your gray value.

Comment: This is a MATLAB question :/

Comment: @AnderBiguri i have given a general solution and a demo example in Python, if user want Matlab code then he can ask for Matlab code.

Comment: I guess such functions for finding contours are available in Matlab too.

Comment: Yes, he wants MATLAB code, that is the entire purpose of tags in Stackoverflow. And as you can see, the tag is [matlab]. So do the functions exist in C++, ruby, perl and whitespace. As long as the language is turing complete it is ensured to have them. That is not the point, though.

Comment: i have never used matlab, may be someone else can provide matlab code :)

Comment: So do not post the answer ;)

Comment: So it means if i have the code then only i can answer? Sudo code does not matters?

Comment: Pseudo code *may* help in some cases. This is not pseudo code, this is code in a different language. Funnily, you are doing exactly what OP is already doing, and your code in another language doesn't even try to solve his problem :/. You translated the code in the question, not given an answer.

Comment: ohh! sorry i could not understand the Matlab code, i only saw the input and output image and i gave my solution and code in python. I understand that my answer deserves downvotes but i won't delete that since it might be useful to users who are looking for Python solution for contour detection.

Comment: But **this is not a solution**